# Keyerror in django restframework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Views.py**

```
class EventCalenderEventListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny,]
    serializer_class = serializer.EventCalenderSerializer
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = json.loads(self.request.GET.get('filter'))
        category = data.get('category')
        query_list = Event.objects.all().values('start_date').distinct()
        date_list = []
        for i in query_list:
            for key, value in i.items():
                date_list.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(value,'%Y-%m-%d'))
        datas = []
        result = {}
        for dates in date_list:
            result[dates]= []
            query = Event.objects.filter(start_date=dates).order_by('start_date')
            for i in query:
                result[dates].append(i)
            datas.append(result)
            result = {}
        return datas
```

**Models.py**

```
class Event(BaseFields):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategory,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    other_event_category = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    meeting_link = models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class EventCalenderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    category = SerializerMethodField()
    status = SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = fields=('id','name','category','start_date','end_date','status')
    def get_category(self, obj):
        category = {}
        if obj.category:
            category['id'] = obj.category.id
            category['name'] = obj.category.name
            return category
        else:
            category = ""
            return category
    def get_status(self,obj):
        current_date =  datetime.strftime(datetime.today(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        start_date = datetime.strftime(obj.start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
        if obj.end_date is not None:
            end_date = datetime.strftime(obj.end_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
            if start_date == end_date and start_date < current_date:
                return "completed"
            elif start_date < current_date and end_date < current_date:
                return "completed"
            elif start_date < current_date and end_date > current_date:
                return "progress"
            elif start_date == current_date:
                return "progress"
            else:
                return "upcoming"
        else:
            if start_date < current_date:
                return "completed"
            elif start_date == current_date:
                return "progress"
            else:
                return "upcomng"
```

[image: error]

**Expecting output:**

```
[
  {
    "2023-06-01": [
      {
        "name": "event 1",
        "start_date": "2023-06-01",
        "end_date": "2023-06-07"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "2023-06-01": [
      {
        "name": "event 2",
        "start_date": "2023-06-01",
        "end_date": "2023-06-07"
      },
      {
        "name": "event 3",
        "start_date": "2023-06-01",
        "end_date": "2023-06-07"
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: The error says that there is no key 'name' in the category dict object that you are trying to access. Are you sure you are expecting the correct key in the dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of `.get_queryset` is what is passed to `.list` method that will serialize and return data ready for display. Currently, you are deforming this into something that does not correspond to your `serializer`:

```
[
    {'2023-06-01': 
        [
            <Event: Event object (1)>, 
            <Event: Event object (2)>, 
            <Event: Event object (3)>
        ]
    }
]
```

Also, that is different from the structure you posted (as expected output) in your question, I will assume that what you built with code is the correct one.

So, basically what you need to do is serialize the list of events inside your key values. We can work around that by overriding the `.list` method. And, loop through your *"QuerySet"* (that is actually an `Array` of dictionaries that contains one key with a list of `Event` objects), in this way serializing this list and recreating your response:

views.py

```
class EventCalenderEventListView(ListAPIView):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        data = []
        for event_date in queryset:
            for key, value in event_date.items():
                serializer = self.get_serializer(value, many=True)
                data.append({key: serializer.data})
        return Response(data)
```

### Alternatively

I propose that you clean your view, by making use of methods provided by the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and that you structure your data in a different manner, so we can directly serialize the data with a `Wrapper`:

serializers.py

```
class EventCalenderSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...


class Wrapper(serializers.Serializer):
    day = serializers.DateField()
    events = EventCalenderSerializer(many=True)
```

views.py

```
class EventCalenderEventListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        AllowAny,
    ]
    serializer_class = Wrapper

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We can go arround the param
        filter_param = self.request.GET.get("filter") or None
        if filter_param:
            filter_param_data = json.loads(filter_param)
            category = filter_param_data.get("category")

        data = []
        date_list = (
            Event.objects.all()
            .values_list("start_date", flat=True)
            .distinct()
        )

        for date in date_list:
            event_list = Event.objects.filter(start_date=date)
            data.append({"day": date, "events": event_list})

        return data
```

Lastly, a response sample, based on `EventCalenderSerializer`. If you want the same fields as expected in your question, then remove the respective ones from your original serializer (same is valid for the previous solution).

```
[
  {
      "day": "2023-06-01",
      "events": [
          {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Event 1",
              "category": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "some category"
              },
              "start_date": "2023-06-01",
              "end_date": "2023-06-07",
              "status": "completed"
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Event 2",
              "category": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "some category"
              },
              "start_date": "2023-06-01",
              "end_date": "2023-06-07",
              "status": "completed"
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "Event 3",
              "category": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "some category"
              },
              "start_date": "2023-06-01",
              "end_date": "2023-06-07",
              "status": "completed"
          }
      ]
  }
]
```